# How to disable the browser scrollbar in a Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism

In my Silverlight application I need to permanently disable the browser scroll bar. When I run the application the browser scroll bar is visible. So I need to disable this one.

Please let me know in which file we should do and the code for disabling the scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

u have to make your UserControle(root userControle) smaller that fit-up in to your browser that's way your browser scroll bar can disable.....

use silverlight navigation template

Answer (score 1):

When using the default aspx-page to display the Silverlight application (the one generated by Visual Studio) usually no scroll bars should appear. But if that is the case that's the place where to look.

Sometimes the browser (especially the Internet Explorer) renders line breaks where there are none. So try to remove any line-breaks from the HTML-markup surrounding the `<object>`-element hosting the Silverlight application.

Example: Convert the following code

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
    </div>
</form>
```

to the following code by removing all linebreaks (I added the `...` to make the code more readable here, leave the original parameters there of course)

```html
<form ...><div><object ...></object><iframe ...></iframe></div></form>
```

In my case that did solve the issue.